# base64-jpeg convert to base64-png

Tags: javascript

I have a base64 string in jpeg format, I need to convert it to base64 in png format. I know that this can be done using canvas and the toDataUrl method. But my jpeg picture has a 24bit color depth, if I put it on the canvas, I will get 32bit at the output.

So, is it possible to convert base64-jpeg to base64-png without intermediaries? Are there any such libraries in JS?

```
  const canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  const c = canv.getContext('2d');
  c.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  const b64jpg = c.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1); // 24bit
  const b64png = c.canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1); // 32bit
```

Comment: PNG and JPEG are inherently very different formats, so I doubt there's a simple way to go without decoding the JPEG image in some way. And I'm basically 100% sure that you'll *have* to do the base64 decoding no matter what else you do.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It is important for me only to save the picture in 24bit format. If this can be done somehow, then I will be glad to see.

Comment: Add your current code.

Comment: Also: *why* is that important? 32 bit PNG is just 24 bit PNG with an alpha layer added. If you have an empty alpha layer that should not add significant size to the output. Explaining your requirements in details might help get answers that are better suited for your problem.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have a thermal printer that only prints 24bit. When I print a 32bit PNG, it starts to behave strangely. Of all formats, it prints only PNG. It prints PNG8, PNG16, PNG32 but changing the picture. The only format that is printed adequately is PNG24

Comment: @JoachimSauer Is there a way to make javascript from png32 to png24. Or how to remove alpha channel from PNG32

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215301/discussion-between---and-joachim-sauer).